# The type or namespace name 'Vectore3' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently following a tutorial on YouTube to make a FirstPerson Movement and get this error in Unity: Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovment\PlayerMovment.cs(13,5): error CS0246: The type or namespace name ’Vectore3' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). Can someone help me?
Here’s the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Movment")]
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;

    float horizontalMovement;
    float verticalMovement;

    Vectore3 moveDirection;

    Rigidbody rb;

    private void Start(){
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.freezeRotation = true;
    }

    private void Update(){
        MyInput();
    }

    void MyInput(){
        horizontalMovement = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        verticaMovement = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        moveDirection = transform.forward * verticalMovement + transform.right * horizontalMovement;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate(){
        MovePlayer();
    }

    void MovePlayer(){
        rb.AddForce(moveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed, ForceMode.Acceleration);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is down to a typo. `Vectore3` should read `Vector3`.

Comment: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)